# Why does Jesus seek out Philip in John 1:43?

Tags: john, jesus, disciple

In John's Gospel, we read that Jesus sought Philip in Galilee:

> **John 1:43-44**: "The next day He purposed to go into Galilee, and He found Philip. And Jesus said to him, 'Follow Me.'”

It seems that on virtually all other occasions — possibly with the exception of Matthew, the disciples *come to Jesus*. Why did Jesus seek out Philip (and Matthew) unlike the other disciples?

Answer (score 4):

Matt 10:1 suggests that 12 of the disciples were "called" by Jesus.

The record in John 1:35-50 is consistent with Jesus deliberately placing Himself where He knew the disciples would be to "arrange" a calling.  He chose men that were deeply interested in spiritual matters and understood the Messianic prophecies.

- Jesus deliberately found Andrew because He knew that Andrew would find Peter
- Jesus deliberately found Philip because He knew that Philip would bring Nathanael
- Jesus deliberately went along the shore of lake Galilee to find James and John

... and so forth.  Thus, the Gospels present Jesus actions, including the calling of the disciples as intentional and planned (presumably by the Holy Spirit).  See Matt 4:19, 9:9, Mark 1:17, 2:14, John 21:19,

In a few cases, Jesus called some others who refused to follow such as in Matt 8:22,  19:21, Mark 8:34, Luke 9:59, etc.

Comment: Interesting points I had not considered. +1.

Comment: Can't do any better.  Good answer.